# How to connect to internet from a Bluetooth-only device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, tizen-wearable-sdk

This might not be a programming question exactly but I'm basically looking for an input on the architecture to use.

Consider this, I have 2 devices-

Device1 (Bluetooth only)

Device2 (Bluetooth + internet access)

I want to do a cloud lookup from Device1.

I was able to implement something similar by writing an android application and installing it on both the devices.

But I'm wondering if there's any smarter way of doing this?

Is it possible to perform a cloud lookup from Device1 'directly', if I setup a teethered bluetooth connection between two devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth  [Personal Area Networking (PAN)](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/PAN.aspx) profile can be used for that scenario. It allows encapsulation and transfer of Ethernet packets over the Bluetooth connection between the two devices.
Then Device2 will act as the access point for the internet.

Comment: I was looking for just an input and your answer is satisfying. Thanks!

Comment: I see you have tizen as tag, do you plan to use BT PAN on gear2 ? I dont think it is possible without rooting the device